# Proper size of Portuguese custard tart

Tags: baking, custard, tart, portuguese-cuisine

On Amazon, I see that most of the egg tart molds have dimensions

- ~7 cm top diameter
- ~4 cm bottom diameter
- ~2 cm height

However, I then see [some](https://www.luisa-paixao.eu/collections/ustensiles-de-cuisine-typiquement-portugais/products/moule-a-pasteis-de-nata-10-pieces) [other](https://www.luisa-paixao.eu/collections/ustensiles-de-cuisine-typiquement-portugais/products/moule-a-pasteis-de-nata-en-inox-5-pieces) molds seemingly from Portugal with dimensions

- 7.2 cm - 7.5 cm top diameter
- ~3.6 cm bottom diameter
- 2.7 cm - 3 cm height

which is a slightly smaller bottom and considerably taller height. My question is how (or whether) these differences in sizes affect the tart, and whether the ones from Amazon or the latter site would give a result that'd be considered closer to a "proper" pastel de nata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what my personal experience is worth: The pastel de nata I ate in Portugal this year (at least from 10 different bakeries) were more in line with a 2 cm height than 3 cm I'd say. I could imagine having more headroom gives you more volume for custard and "protection" against overflowing, but other than that you could probably even use a muffin form and be fine.

Comment: when improvising (i.e. I don't have access to proper forms for pastéis de nata or empadinhas), I prefer muffin forms than egg tart forms - since the custard rises when baking, a muffin form gives better custard-to-crust ratio while preventing overflowing.